# Possible to load image/png data after link redirect?

Tags: javascript, wikia

I have this problem... I'm working on a project which loads names from a JSON file (this is not important).

The thing is I use a Wikia **Special:Filepath** link to get my images. So when I type in my browser: http://2007.runescape.wikia.com/wiki/Special:Filepath/Abyssal_head.png it returns this image link: http://img1.wikia.nocookie.net/__cb20140108135954/2007scape/images/0/0f/Abyssal_head.png.

Is there a way to work around this redirect so I can properly load it with an ajax call?
Whenever I try to do this first link I get this error (which is normal because it can't find the correct headers I think):

```
XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://2007.runescape.wikia.com/wiki/Special:Filepath/Abyssal_head.png. No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'null' is therefore not allowed access.
```

All help is welcome.

Comment: What do you want to do exactly?

Comment: to view the image you can directly gave the link in a tag. like this 
<img src="http://2007.runescape.wikia.com/wiki/Special:Filepath/Abyssal_head.png" />
So you dont worry about the redirect. the image will be shown

Comment: Hi Shabeer! Yes I know that this works but it bothers me. I would like to load all the images, put them in an array or an object and show them when all the images are loaded. There is my problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Special:Filepath` is useful for linking to files from within a wiki, but if you want to programmatically fetch paths, using the API will give you a lot more flexibility. To get the filepath, just use the `prop=imageinfo` and `iiprop=url` parameters, like [this](http://2007.runescape.wikia.com/api.php?action=query&titles=Image:Abyssal_head.png&prop=imageinfo&iiprop=url&format=json):

[`api.php?action=query
        &titles=Image:Abyssal_head.png
        &prop=imageinfo
        &iiprop=url
        &format=json`](http://2007.runescape.wikia.com/api.php?action=query&titles=Image:Abyssal_head.png&prop=imageinfo&iiprop=url&format=json)

This will give you a json object like this

```
{"query": {
    "normalized":...,
    "pages":{
        "28052":{
            "pageid":28052,
            "ns":6,
            "title":"File:Abyssal head.png",
            "imagerepository":"local",
            "imageinfo":[
                {
                    "url":"http:\/\/img1.wikia.nocookie.net\/__cb20140108135954\/2007scape\/images\/0\/0f\/Abyssal_head.png",
                    "descriptionurl":"http:\/\/2007.runescape.wikia.com\/wiki\/File:Abyssal_head.png"
                }
            ]
        }
    }
}}
```

...with your desired url in `query.pages.{PAGE}.imageinfo.url`

You can query for multiple file at ones, separating their titles with `|`.

See [`2007.runescape.wikia.com/api.php`](http://2007.runescape.wikia.com/api.php) for full documentation.

Comment: Thanks man! This is really usefull! Now I could load all images before showing them on screen!